# Udev RUN rule to run touch has no effect

Tags: udev

I've created the file bellow

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/10-tuned.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS}=="Charging", RUN+="touch /home/fx/charg"
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS}=="Discharging", RUN+="touch /home/fx/disc"
```

but if I connect or disconnect the power cable no files created. After creating this file I did execute

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

for rules reloading. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed `touch` to `/usr/bin/touch` and it worked. The full path of executables is needed for the `RUN` directive (otherwise the executable must be in `/lib/udev`):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS}=="Charging", RUN+="/usr/bin/touch /home/fx/charg"
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS}=="Discharging", RUN+="/usr/bin/touch /home/fx/disc"
```

Comment: @Sneetsher Thank you for reminding. I accepted it.