# how to execute a script every time any USB get mounted

Tags: linux, mount, usb, monitoring, usb-drive

I use a script that writes all mountpoints of my devices to a textfile using df. How can I execute my script every time any device (especially USB) is mounted?

script to execute:

```
#!/bin/bash
# save all mountpoints to textfile
df -h /dev/sd*| grep /dev/sd| awk '{print $6}' > /home/<user>/FirstTextfile
# do something
while read line 
do  
echo "mountpoint:${line%/*}/ devicename:${line##*/}}" >> home/<user>/AnotherTextfile
```

Debian 8.0 (jessie), Linux 3.16.0, Gnome 3.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a udev rule which first mounts the USB-drive and second runs my-script

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/11-media-by-label-with-pmount.rules

KERNEL!="sd[a-z]*", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
ACTION=="add", PROGRAM!="/sbin/blkid %N", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"

# Get label
PROGRAM=="/sbin/blkid -o value -s LABEL %N", ENV{dir_name}="%c"

# use basename to correctly handle labels such as ../mnt/foo
PROGRAM=="/usr/bin/basename '%E{dir_name}'", ENV{dir_name}="%c"
ENV{dir_name}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"

ACTION=="add", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/su YOURUSERNAME -c '/usr/bin/pmount %N %E{dir_name}'", RUN+="/etc/udev/scripts/my-script.sh"
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/su YOURUSERNAME -c '/usr/bin/pumount /media/%E{dir_name}'"
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

note:
The drive is mounted by root but can be unmounted by the given user. In the last block you have to change YOURUSERNAME with your username and /etc/udev/scripts/my-script.sh with the path to your script. Source and more scripts: https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Udev#USB_Ger.C3.A4te_automatisch_einbinden

---

Another solution is to use a udisks wrapper like [devmon](https://igurublog.wordpress.com/downloads/script-devmon/).

Comment: Or `findmnt --poll`.

Answer (score 1):

Linux has no hook that runs when a device is mounted in all circumstances.

[Udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) handles devices when they appear in the system. It can run a command at that point ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155395/udev-run-rule-to-run-touch-has-no-effect)). Although you can run `mount` from udev, this conflicts with [Udisks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks), and in particular doesn't work on systems using [systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd). [It's possible to monitor mounts performed by Udisks](http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/UDisksMountMonitor.html), but I don't know how to do that from the command line. There's a [Python example on the Gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Udisks#Python_Scripting).

There is a facility to monitor arbitrary system calls: the [audit system](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-Defining_Audit_Rules_and_Controls.html). The following command triggers a log entry whenever the `mount` system call returns:

```
auditctl -a exit,always -S mount
```

You can trigger a program from an audit event via [audisp](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_security/data/sec_audit_audisp.html), but this isn't very convenient: you need to write a plugin that parses the audit event.