# How to execute a script after every systemd automount?

Tags: mount, systemd, automounting

I am trying to setup a system such that a script gets executed everytime any USB storage device is mounted (in this case, automounted by systemd). Based on a few references [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208815/how-to-execute-a-script-everytime-any-usb-get-mounted), [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=207050) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078579/systemd-execute-script-on-every-mount), systemd allows for the execution of custom scripts after a specific device is mounted, but these either:

- Need a specific device or mountpoint.
- Use udev, which triggers too early, and holds the mounting process.
- Use audits or logs, which isn't very satisfying.

Is there anyway to be *less* specific in systemd units, allowing for the use of `ExecStart` after any succesful (auto)mount?

Comment: another unsatisfying solution is `udisksctl monitor` which shows each disk being mounted.

Comment: Have your USB storage the same number of partition?

Comment: I have no knowledge about the drive's structure. All I know is that partitions are going to get automounted, and the script should trigger for every one of them. I'd like the solution to stay generic like that.

Answer (score 0):

I can only poiting the way.

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/bb-clam.rules 
KERNEL=="sd[b-z]*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="clamtk.service"
```

this triggers my unit clamtk.service `cat /etc/systemd/system/clamtk.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=clamtk
Requires=dev-media0.device

[Service]
Type=simple
User=alex
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/local/bin/clam"
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=15s

[Install]
WantedBy=multiuser.target
```

But this works only good if your unit is started as user, and the unit is triggerd also for usb-harddrives.